# Dot Product and Outer Product Identity

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I've been looking into some relatively basic differential geometry recently, specifically offset/parallel curves. I came across one question on [Bezier offset self intersections](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952351/bezier-offset-self-intersections) and I've been going through the equations in the accepted answer however one part isn't clear to me. After the line "and we have" just above the second image there an equation:

$$\cfrac{d \widehat{\mathbf{n}}}{d t} 
    = \frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf{n}(t)\rVert_{}} \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t} 
      - \frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf{n}(t)\rVert_{}^3} \left(\mathbf{n}(t) \cdot \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t}\right) \mathbf{n}(t)
    = \frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf{n}(t)\rVert_{}} \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t} 
      - \frac{1}{\lVert\mathbf{n}(t)\rVert_{}^3} \left[\mathbf{n}(t) \otimes \mathbf{n}(t)\right] \cdot \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t}$$

What I don't fully understand is how we arrive at the equivalence:

$$\left(\mathbf{n}(t) \cdot \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t}\right) \mathbf{n}(t)
    =  \left[\mathbf{n}(t) \otimes \mathbf{n}(t)\right] \cdot \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t}$$

One the left we have a scalar multiplying the normal vector and on the right we have matrix-vector multiplication (I assume the dot on the right hand side is an error).

I've done the working out and I'm happy that the two expressions result in the same vector. What I'm not sure on is how the we recognise they are equivalent. Is there an identity I'm not aware of involved? I've managed to come up with the following:

$$\left(\mathbf{n}(t) \cdot \cfrac{d \mathbf{n}}{d t}\right) \mathbf{n}(t) =  \left( \mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{n}' \right)\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{n}\left( \mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{n}' \right) =\left(\mathbf{n} \mathbf{n}^T\right) \mathbf{n}' = \left( \mathbf{n} \otimes \mathbf{n}\right)\mathbf{n'}$$

Having written this out I'm fairly sure this is correct. Is it a simple case of being able to move $ \left( \mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{n}' \right)$ around because it results in a scalar and then just moving the brackets so we can bring in the outer product?  I'm not particularly familiar with outer products so I feel I might be missing something. Also, is there any particular significance relating to the use of curly and square brackets here?

Comment: Yes: Your associativity-of-matrix-multiplication argument is correct, and the "right way" to explain the computation. <> There is no apparent significance here in the shapes of brackets.